# PHP Geoplugin not working

Tags: php, geolocation

I need to redirect if the user is from United States or from any other country that does not speak Portuguese. My code:

```
    require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
    $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
    $geoplugin->locate();
    // create a variable for the country code
    $var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
    $arrCountryCode = array('BR', 'PT', 'CV', 'GW', 'AO', 'MZ', 'TL', 'ST', 'GQ');
    $hasEn = explode('', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]); 
    // $geoplugin = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=".$geoplugin->ip));

    // redirect based on country code && if the url has not /en && if is the first view:
    if(!in_array($var_country_code, $arrCountryCode) && $hasEn[1] != 'en' && $_COOKIE['redirect'] == '') {
        setcookie('redirect', 'true'); //allow to delete /en
        header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].'/en'.$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
    }
}
```

Everyone is being to redirect to /en, even if it is from Brazil. What is wrong with my code?

P.S. using the [geoplugin library](https://github.com/Perlkonig/grav-plugin-geoplugin/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 3):

### #1

Please turn on the display of PHP errors and warnings: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
You may see an error from [geoplugin](https://github.com/Perlkonig/grav-plugin-geoplugin/blob/master/README.md), like:

> Error geoPlugin class Error: Cannot retrieve data. Either compile PHP with cURL support or enable allow_url_fopen in php.ini on line number 137

### #2

```
 $hasEn = explode('', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
```

This code will set the variable `$hasEn` to `false` (and produce a warning) because you're using an empty delimiter.

Then, `$hasEn[1] != 'en'` will always evaluate to `true`. Thus, the users would be unnecessarily redirected once from the `en` site as well.

Comment: Ok, I fixed this:
`$hasEn = preg_match('/en/', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);`
`if(!in_array($var_country_code, $arrCountryCode) && !$hasEn && $_COOKIE['redirect'] == '') {`

But no make sense because my var_country_code is BR, so should not be redirect...

Comment: maybe the problem is on server, because I tested the code in another website and worked...

Comment: As said - please turn on error reporting, then you will possibly see the reason. 
It could be server configuration (e.g. curl extension not available).

Comment: Please edit your question to add the errors reported.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect is hard-coded to direct people to /en:

`header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].'/en'.$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);`

Instead of using the return value `$var_country_code`

Should probably look more like this:
`header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].'/'.$var_country_code.'/'.$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);`